# SFX/Foley :Female/Woman Footsteps on different surfaces needed, which library? 

Tags: sfx, foley, footsteps, sound-library

Hi Everyone,

I'm working on a whiteboard animation and I want the listener to follow the main character (a woman) walking around her office environment. I have some footsteps in my library but i've used them so many times already in other projects, I want something fresh sounding. Unfortunately I don't have the time or place to record foley.

Can anyone recommend a SFX library with nice multi-surface footsteps and different perspectives? I've already checked out sounddogs and sfxonline.eu but either preview quality is very low or the samples sound dull.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Arnoud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sound-ideas.com/artfoley.html

http://www.hollywoodedge.com/Foley-Footsteps-Sonic-Boon-P39C8.aspx

Comment: Thanks Stavrosound! I went with the Sonic Boom. I will have to wait quite a while though, because they only ship it on cd. There's no digital download version available... 

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add http://www.sound-ideas.com/sfx-kit.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

Try this footsteps [patch](http://www.signo-sfx-instruments.com). I'm currently working on a footsteps library for Kontakt, EXS24 and Structure.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a number of footsteps samples on different surfaces can be found at http://rocksuresoundz.com/store/foley/footsteps/